# Market structure determination

Tags: elasticity, markets, price

I will be conducting a research about the market structure of an outdoor farmers market. I wanted to know what kind of survey questions could help me for example to determine the PES of the market or anything else that I could use in order to determine the market structure. 
I already will survey people about how do they choose the shop, how much time they spend finding a shop, if they have the information of the cheapest shop and how often do they return to the same store. In addition to that, I will be observing the price changes for about a month, and also use the Herfindahl-Hirschman Index (HHI).

Comment: Perhaps you could also edit in information about what exactly you mean by market structure, and what exactly is the wording of these questions that you already have in your survey.

Comment: By market structure I mean to what extent is it similar to perfect competition, monopolistic competition or oligopoly for example. The questions I will use in my survey are the following **1** How often do you visit the same shop? **2** Are you aware of the cheapest and the most expensive _good x_ in this outdoor farmer market? **3** Most and least important factors affecting your choice of the shop? **4** How much time do you spend shopping for _goodx_ ? I would survey the customers of the market this way offering limited set of answers as A; B; C; D.